# Discord.py - How to make people wait some time to use a command again?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command "beg" but I don't want people to use it always and earn money, so is it possible to make people wait some time to use the command again?

Comment: Have a dictionary of people and the last time they used the function.

Answer (score 0):

`discord.ext.commands` has a decorator function `cooldown`. Takes 3 parameters:

per => after how many uses to occur

rate => how seconds to wait

type => cooldown type. can be guild, user, channel, role

**In Cogs**

```
@commands.command(name="ping")
@commands.cooldown(per=1, rate=3.0, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def ping(self, ctx):
  await ctx.send("Pong!")
```

**Not in cogs**

```
@bot.command(name="ping")
@commands.cooldown(per=1, rate=3.0, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Pong!")
```

Comment: For what **self** is needed?